# What causes this failure to change the value of a service variable from a component, in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on a **Users** app with Angular 9 and Angular Material. The list component should display, for each user, the username and avatar, in a table row.

For this purpose, I have a list component and a list service.

The service is simple:

```
export class UsersListService {

  searchQuery = '';

  usersUrl = `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=${this.searchQuery}`;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getUsers():Observable<User[]> {
    if (this.searchQuery.length >= 3){
      return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.usersUrl}`)
      .pipe(map(response => response['items']));
    }
  }

}
```

In the list component I have:

```
<form [formGroup]="searchUser">
  <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
    <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="search" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (keyup)="applySearch()">
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" *ngIf="searchQuery" (click)="clearSearch()">
  <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</form>
```

and

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  pageTitle = 'Users';

  usersList:User[];

  constructor(private UsersListService:UsersListService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  usersTableData: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['photo', 'login', 'actions'];

  searchUser = this.fb.group({});

  searchQuery = ""

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit(): void  {
    // User list
    if (this.UsersListService.searchQuery.length >= 3){
      this.UsersListService.getUsers().subscribe(
        usersList => { 
          this.usersList = usersList;
          this.usersTableData = new MatTableDataSource(usersList);
          this.usersTableData.paginator = this.paginator;
        },
        error => { }
      );
    } 
    

    //Add the search box
    this.searchUser.addControl('search', this.fb.control(''));
  }
  
  clearSearch() {
    this.searchQuery = "";
    this.applySearch();
  }

  applySearch() {
    this.UsersListService.searchQuery = this.searchQuery;
  }
```

As it can be observed above, I try to change the value of the variable `searchQuery` from the component. More exactly, in the `applySearch()` method.

For a reason I have not figured out, this fails (even if there is no error in the terminal or browser).

What is missing?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, but one oddity that stands out is you're checking the `searchQuery` length in both the component and the service. Maybe that check is failing in one or both places?

Comment: What do you mean by "_this fails_"? Is the HTTP call not triggered?

Comment: @MichaelD The value of `searchQuery` does not change when change the value of `<input matInput formControlName="search" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (keyup)="applySearch()">`.

Comment: Okay. But you're attempting to trigger the HTTP call **only once** at the beginning of the component in the `ngOnInit` hook. The call won't be triggered even when `searchQuery` gets longer than 3 characters.

Comment: @MichaelD What about `applySearch() {
    this.UsersListService.searchQuery = this.searchQuery;
  }`? Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding from my comment, you're trying to trigger the HTTP call **only once** at the beginning of the component in the `ngOnInit` hook. It doesn't matter if the assignment  `this.UsersListService.searchQuery = this.searchQuery` works.

Instead you could use RxJS `fromEvent` function with Angular template reference variable to capture the `keyup` event. And map to the `this.UsersListService.getUsers()` function using a higher order mapping operator (I am using `exhaustMap` to ignore incoming events during the HTTP call).

Try the following

Controller

```js
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

import { fromEvent, Subject, of } from "rxjs";
import { exhaustMap, takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({...})
export class ListComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  closed$ = new Subject<any>();
  searchQuery = "";

  @ViewChild("search") search: ElementRef<any>;
  ...

  constructor(...) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.search.nativeElement, "keyup").pipe(
      takeUntil(this.closed$),
      exhaustMap(_ => {
        this.UsersListService.searchQuery = this.searchQuery; // <-- why is this needed though?
        return (this.searchQuery.length >= 3) 
          ? this.UsersListService.getUsers()
          : of(false) // <-- return `false` if search query is less than 3 characters
      })
    ).subscribe(
      usersList => {
        if (!!usersList) { // <-- proceed only if `usersList` is defined
          this.usersList = usersList;
          this.usersTableData = new MatTableDataSource(usersList);
          this.usersTableData.paginator = this.paginator;
        }
      },
      error => { }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closed$.next();
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<input #search matInput formControlName="search" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery">
```